# Angular Reactive Form Control only observes input from first form control

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to build a reactive form using a form builder class. I am noticing that it is only observing the validators of the first name form control and it is only observing the changes of the the first name class.

This is the relevant TS code but I have also built a stackblitz with the minimum HTML to make the component. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cosgyz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Why is this able to pick up the value changes from first name and not any of the other inputs?

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.profile = await this.userService.getUser();
    this.settings = await this.userControllerService.getUserProfileSettings().toPromise();
    this.profileSettings = Object.assign(this.profile, this.settings);
    console.log(this.profileSettings);

    this.profileSettingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName : [this.profileSettings.firstName, [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ] ],
      lastName : [this.profileSettings.lastName, [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ] ],
      displayName : [this.profileSettings.displayName, [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ] ],
      birthDate : [this.profileSettings.birthDate, Validators.required],
      displayBirthDate : [this.profileSettings.displayBirthDate, Validators.required],
      location : [this.profileSettings.location, Validators.required],
      displayLocation : [this.profileSettings.displayLocation, Validators.required],
      phoneNumber : [this.profileSettings.phoneNumber, [ Validators.maxLength(11), Validators.pattern(`[- +()0-9]+`) ] ],
      displayPhoneNumber : [this.profileSettings.displayPhoneNumber, Validators.required],
      email : [this.profileSettings.email,[ Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern(`^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$`) ] ],
      displayEmail : [this.profileSettings.displayEmail, Validators.required]
    });


    this.profileSettingsForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(this.profileSettingsForm.value);
      this.profileSettings.birthDate = value.birthDate;
      this.profileSettings.email = value.email;
      this.profileSettings.firstName = value.firstName;
      this.profileSettings.lastName = value.lastName;
      this.profileSettings.displayName = value.displayName;
      this.profileSettings.location = value.location;
      this.profileSettings.displayLocation = value.displayLocation;
      this.profileSettings.phoneNumber = value.phoneNumber;
    });
  }
```

Comment: `fromControlName`... typo. Also you don't need `[value]`, the value is in the formcontrol

Comment: Why did you call .toPromise() on getUserProfileSettings() but not on getUser() ?

Comment: It had to do with the HTML thank you @AT82.

Comment: To answer @Mustafa it's how the service was set up